# Opening ArcGIS Desktop on specific license level?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-license-manager

We are on Citrix and would like to provide 3 shortcuts to our users so they can launch the three license levels (ArcView, ArcEditor and ArcInfo).  We can't do this through desktop admin as the users don't have admin rights and we would like an intuitive workflow anyway.

How do others provide access to the different license levels in their organisations for the users to quickly open the product license that they want?

Comment: You might want to ask your ESRI support. In my experience this is the sort of question they can answer quickly.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you want to control the license on a per-application basis, you could create batch files that set the ESRI_SOFTWARE_CLASS variable to either `Professional`,`Editor`,`Viewer` and then start ArcMap/ArcCatalog.

[image]

A `SET ESRI_SOFTWARE_CLASS=Viewer` statement will switch to ArcView:
[image]

And a `SET ESRI_SOFTWARE_CLASS=Editor` will switch to ArcEditor:
[image]

If you create the batch files, the ESRI_SOFTWARE_CLASS variable is only in scope for that instance of the application.  So you could start an ArcView and ArcEditor at the same time (if the license manager has available licenses).

[image]

Alternatively, a user could set a user system variable of `ESRI_SOFTWARE_CLASS` to the desired license and then every application would be at the same license level.

Related Bug: http://support.esri.com/en/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/32729

Comment: Excellent! Do you know if this works when the user does not have admin rights?

Comment: I think so, but I haven't tested it. By setting the `ESRI_SOFTWARE_CLASS` in a variable, that would create a user variable, not a system variable.

Comment: Here's a knowledge base article: http://support.esri.com/en/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/24633

Comment: Perfect answer, vote +answer!

Comment: I have a .NET exe that I've been using on 10.1 (but should work for other versions): https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1156285/ArcMapEditor.exe  If you rename the exe to ArcMap<ESRI_SOFTWARE_CLASS> (e.g. `ArcMapBasic.exe` or `ArcMapProfessional.exe`), it will start the ArcMap with that software class.

Comment: I've updated my batch files implementing this approach to be version agnostic: https://github.com/maphew/arcplus/tree/master/SysAdmin

Answer (score 1):

*From our internal KB article, which I adapted from @jay-cummin's [post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/24008/108) here, and then wrote some scripts to make using them quick and painless:*

As many of you have discovered, at times you can’t switch from ArcGIS Basic to ArcGIS Advanced because the radio buttons in ArcGIS Administrator are disabled:

[image: ArcGIS Administrator with disabled controls]

Fortunately there is a workaround, set the license level in an environment variable first and then run ArcMap/Catalog. We’ve placed scripts for this in <strike>Z:\Tools</strike> [[GitHub]](https://github.com/envygeo/arcplus/tree/master/SysAdmin):

`ArcMap-Advanced.bat` run ArcMap using Advanced (ArcInfo) license
`ArcMap-Editor.bat` run ArcMap using Editor (ArcEditor) license
`ArcMap-Viewer.bat` run ArcMap using Viewer (Basic) license

I actually prefer the workaround to the original method: you don’t have to close all your sessions down first just because you want to run an Advanced-only tool for 5 minute job like Create Random Points, and you can run Advanced and Basic side by side at the same time.

You can also set license server this way. Port number and `@` are optional. ([ref](https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000002010)):

```
ARCGIS_LICENSE_FILE=<TCP/IP_port_number>@<license_manager_hostname>
```