# Feature Class To Geodatabase => ERROR 000210: Cannot create output

Tags: enterprise-geodatabase, sql-server, arcgis-9.3, error-000210

error messages:

```
Executing: FeatureClassToGeodatabase E:\jags20120321.mdb\ch_cs "Database Connections\Connection to localhost.sde" "Database Connections\Connection to localhost.sde"
Start Time: Sat Jun 16 13:32:28 2012
Running script FeatureClassToGeodatabase...
Failed to convert E:\jags20120321.mdb\ch_cs. ERROR 000210: Cannot create output Database Connections\Connection to localhost.sde\jags.DBO.ch_cs
Failed to execute (CopyFeatures).

Completed script FeatureClassToGeodatabase...
Executed (FeatureClassToGeodatabase) successfully.
End Time: Sat Jun 16 13:32:37 2012 (Elapsed Time: 9.00 seconds)
```

Those are the error messages.  I don't know what's the reason.  I use arcgis 9.3, arcgis sde 9.3, and sql server 2008.

Answer (score 5):

Sounds like a permissions issue.  Try working through these steps:

http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2008/09/05/digging-deeper-troubleshooting-geoprocessing-errors-when-using-arcsde

Comment: this link leads to a general page...

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if you forget to raise your [license level](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/get-started/installation-guide/the-arcgis-administrator.htm) to Standard (arceditor) or Advanced (arcinfo).

Also see [Opening ArcGIS Desktop on specific license level?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/24002/opening-arcgis-desktop-on-specific-license-level)