# Change ArcGIS License using Script

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-license-manager

I am using ArcGIS Desktop 10 and we have three different servers for accessing concurrent use licenses of ArcView, ArcEditor and ArcInfo. So, whenever I need to switch to other product, I have close currently using Catalog or ArcMap and open ArcGIS Administrator and then change the software product and License manager (Server IP) manually. So, is there any way to change the software product and License manager (Server IP) using script or batch file?

Comment: You need to change the HKEY_[LOCAL_MACHINE]\SOFTWARE\ESRI using windows regedit the batch can be created but a simple edit will be just as quick http://support.esri.com/en/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/33925

Comment: You can change the license type via a batch file (http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/31617/3137), I'm not sure about changing the license server's IP address.

Comment: @ipaddress can be changed in regedit or make a path environment - though ther is a serious bug NIM081698 http://support.esri.com/en/downloads/patches-servicepacks/view/productid/160/metaid/1888